# How do you publish on-chain code to mainnet and testnet?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, testnet, mainnet, lovelace-academy

I've understand that the on-chain code is stored in the blockchain through Playground module which is in sync against a local node. But how to "publish" this code to run anywhere? It's an accessible process, It must have some "certification"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all on-chain code isn't stored in the blockchain, the hash of on-chain code is.

To use on-chain validator on testnet or mainnet steps are:

1. Compile on-chain code into plutus script
2. Generate address from plutus script
3. Lock funds into plutus script address ([Don't forget Datum!!!](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3069))
4. Pass plutus script for validation to unlock funds from plutus script address

You can try going trough [Alonzo exercises](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/main/Alonzo-solutions/exercise3/e3SampleSolution.md) for an example how to do all of these steps.

And as for certification I don't think there is an official available certification [yet](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/10/25/new-certification-levels-for-smart-contracts-on-cardano/)

Comment: I think that statement - that on-chain code is not stored on the blockchain - can be a little misleading. It might not be stored (or even executed) directly in that first locking transaction, but when you compose a transaction to spend those funds that transaction will hold the script, which will be stored and made visible on the blockchain and it is also executed directly on-chain by every node validating the transaction. Please correct me if Im wrong here.

Comment: (Looking at cardano-db-sync it even creates a table for the scripts that it takes directly from the blockchain: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/2a0600a16425bce26b4973debc28cddfb45c6eb3/doc/schema.md#script)

Comment: To add to the answer, here's two resources on how to publish the on-chain code: https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/howtos/exporting-a-script.html
https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/Plutus-transactions (scroll down to 3. Create your transaction with the accompanying Plutus script(s))

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be true. The `--tx-in-script-file` param of `cardano-cli transaction build` is saving the file in the transaction, so a given node can run the script code from that transaction.